# Unknow field error in Gatsby GraphQL for custom query

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I am usingGatsby with GraphQL. Getting unknown field error as follows:

```
GraphQL Error Encountered 2 error(s):
- Unknown field 'allBlogPost' on type 'Query'. Source: document `homeAymanDesktopFirstSrcPagesIndexJs2258072279` file: `GraphQL request`
  
  GraphQL request:3:3
  2 |   {
  3 |       posts: allBlogPost {
    |   ^
  4 |           nodes {
- Unknown field 'blogPost' on type 'Query'.

      file: /home/ayman/Desktop/first/src/templates/post.js
```

Here is my `post.js` template file:

```js
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

export default ({ data }) => {
    console.log(data)
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{data.post.title}</h1>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.post.html }} />
        </div>
    )
}

export const query = graphql`
    query($id: String!) {
        post: blogPost(id: { eq: $id }) {
            title
            html
        }
    }
`
```

My `gatsby-node.js` configuration can be found in this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/p25UDrsd)

My GraphiQL:

[image]

---

## Update

After adding Asciidoc file in `content/posts` and `content/articles` , getting this error:

```
Cannot query field "slug" on type "BlogPost".

File: gatsby-node.js:89:16


 ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle:

Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined



  TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined
  
  - gatsby-node.js:99
```

Comment: I guess your query is either broken in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` isn't?

Comment: Added screenshot in question for reference

Answer (score 1):

Your code is breaking in the `gatsby-node.js`, not in the template (at least for now).

Try using an `async`/`await` approach in your `createPage` API, something like:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions
    const postTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/post.js`)
 
    const postsQuery = await graphql(`
        {
            posts: allBlogPost {
                nodes {
                    id
                    slug
                }
            }
        }
    `);

  if (postsQuery.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`);

    return;
  }

        postsQuery.data.posts.nodes.forEach( node => {
            createPage({
                path: node.slug,
                component: postTemplate,
                context: {
                    id: node.id,
                },
            })
        })
```

It seems that you can't create your own schema properly. Ensure that your validations are correct:

```
if (node.internal.type === `Asciidoc`)
```

Comment: Consoling error `reporter.panicOnBuild([`ayman` + postsQuery.errors]);` gives `GraphQLError: Cannot query field "allBlogPost" on type "Query". Did you mean "allBlogPostCollection"?`

Comment: Yes, `allBlogPost` it's not a node :/. In your `localhost:8000/___graphql` you are querying for `allBlogPostCollection`

Comment: `allBlogPost` does not exist. See updated Screenshot. I require both `allBlogPost` and `allBlogPostCollection`

Comment: Is this condition being validated? `node.internal.type === 'Asciidoc'`

Comment: I forgot to add asciidoc file. After adding that getting this error `- Unknown field 'slug' on type '[BlogPost!]!'. Source: document homeAymanDesktopFirstSrcPagesIndexJs2258072279 file: GraphQL request`

Comment: Try to debug your `post` and your `node.pageAttributes`